# Are there any list of Nagardevta/gramdevta of famous Indian cities?

Tags: gods, devi, deity

A Nagardevta/Gramadevta is guardian deity of village who is worshipped by people of that Grama(village) and the deity protects the village. I am wondering who are the Nagardevta/gramadevta of famous Indian cities like Delhi , Mumbai , Chennai , Kolkata , Bangalore , Lucknow, Patna, Hyderabad, Pune, Bhubaneshwar, Indore, Bhopal ,Jaipur  etc. . Does anyone know about it ?

Comment: Mumba Devi (Mumbai), Kal Bhairav (Ujjain), Vishwanath (Varanasi), Kasba Ganapati (Pune), Yogmaya (Delhi), Govind Dev ji (Jaipur), Annamma (Bangalore), Chenna Kesava Perumal (Chenni), Kali (Kolkata), Patan Devi (Patana), Peddamma (Hyderabad), Lingaraja (Bhubaneshwar), Annapurna (Indore)... don't hv valid scriptural references..hence, putting in comments..

Comment: Padmanabha Swamy i.e. Vishnu (Thiruvananthapuram), Shiva in the form of Eranakulathappan (Kochi), Meenakshi Amma (Madurai), Chamundi (Mysore), etc

Comment: Mahakali (Kolkata), Durga (Dhaka, the original idol was shifted to Kolkata during Partition & a new idol was consecrated in the original temple, Pokhara), Kamakhya (Gauhati), Lingaraja (Bhuvaneshwar), Jagannath (Puri), Viraja (Jajpur), Bhadrakali (Bhadrak), Katakchandi (Cuttack), Kamakshi-Ekambareshwara-Varadaraja (Kanchipuram), Ranganatha (Srirangam), Nataraja (Chidambaram), Ranchhorji (Dwaraka), Shiva as Sthanu (Thaneshwara), Govindajiu (Vrindavana, the original idol is currently in Jaipur), Mahabaleshwara (Gokarna), Pashupatinatha (Kathmandu), Surya (Multan, temple demolished around 990 AD)

Answer (score 1):

Kaal Bhairav is said to be the “ruler” of Kashi(I don’t know if that necessarily means **protector**),in the Kalabhairav Ashtakam by Adi Shankaracharya,in all 8 verses)

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Who is adorned by lotus-feet which is reverred and served by Indra (Devaraj), Who has a Yagya-thread made up of snake, Who has the moon on His forehead, Who is the abode of mercy, Who has been sung by Narad and other celestial singers, and Whose clothes are the directions.||1||

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Who is resplendent like millions of sun, Who absolves the ocean of cycle of rebirth, Who is supreme, Who has a blue neck, Who bestows us with our desires, Who has three-eyes, Who is the end of Kaal, Who has lotus-like eyes, Who has immortal monodent weapon, and Who is immortal.||2||

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Who has monodent, spade, a cord and punishment in His hands, Who is the cause behind the beginning, Who has a grey (smeared) body, Who is the first Deva, Who is imperishable, Who is free from illness and health, Who is immensely mighty, Who is the Lord, and Who loves the special Tandava dance.||3||

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Who is the bestower of desires and salvation, Who has an enticing appearance form, Who is endears His devotees, Who is static, Who takes various manifestations and forms the world, and Who has a beautiful golden waist-thread with small melodious bells.||4||

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Who is the maintainer of righteousness, Who is the destroyer of unrighteous paths, Who liberates us from the ties of Karma or deeds, Who bestows us with shyness, Who is splendid, and Whose organ-groups are decorated with a beautiful cord of golden color.||5||

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Who has feet adorned by two sandals made of gold which is possessing a resplendent shine, Who is eternal, Who is induplicable, Who bestows our desires to us, Who is without desires, Who destroys the pride of death (as in is supreme to death), and Who liberates soul by His teeth.||6||

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Whose loud roar is enough to destroy all the manifestations created by the lotus-born Brahma, Whose (merciful) glance is enough to destroy all the sins, Who is the powerful ruler, Who gives the eight-powers¹, and Who wears a garland of skull-caps.||7||

> I sing praise of Kalabhairav, Who is the ruler of the city Kashi, Who is the leader of the ghosts and spirits, Who showers immense glory, Who absolves people dwelling in Kashi from their sins and righteous deeds, Who is splendor, Who has explained the path of righteousness, Who is eternally old, and Who is the controller of the universe.||8||

> Those who study these eight verses on Kalabhairav — which is enticing, which is a source of knowledge and liberation, which increases righteousness of a person, and which destroys grief, attachment, depression, greed, anger an heat — move towards the proximity of the feet of Shiv (Kalabhairav), necessarily.||9||

Comment: I  am not sure how your answer is related to the question

Comment: @Himanshu The stotra mentioning Bhairavji as “ruler of Kashi” is implying “protector” as well,hence answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

We get a list of several Kuladevatās, in reference to Dharmāraṇya, that manifested from the body of goddess Pārvatī in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa.

[Chapter 21](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423642.html) - Dharmāraṇya-khaṇḍa - Book 3 - Brāhma-khaṇḍa

> व्यास उवाच ।
>
> तया चोत्पादिता राजञ्छरीरा त्कुलदेवताः ॥ १.क ॥
>  भट्टारिकी १तथा छत्रा २
> ओविका ३ ज्ञानजा तथा ४ ॥ १.ख ॥
>  भद्रकाली च ५ माहेशी ६ सिंहोरी ७
> धनमर्द्दनी ॥ २.क ॥
>  गात्रा ९ शांता १० शेषदेवी ११ वाराही १२ भद्रयोगिनी १३
> ॥ २.ख ॥
>  योगेश्वरी १४ मोहलज्जा १५ कुलेशी १६ शकुलाचिता ॥ ३.क ॥
>  तारणी १८ वन
> कानंदा १९ चामुंडा २० च सुरेश्वरी २१ ॥ ३.ख ॥
>  दारभट्टारिकेत्या २२ द्या
> प्रत्येका शतधा पुनः ।
>  उत्पन्नाः शक्तयस्तस्मिन्नानारूपान्विताः शुभाः ।
> अतः परं प्रवक्ष्यामि प्रवरण्यथ देवताः ॥ ४ ॥
>
> > 1. to. 4. O king, the Kuladevatās (family deities) were produced by her
> >    (Pārvatī) from her body. 
> >    They are: 
> >    (1) Bhaṭṭārikī,
> >     (2) Chatrā,
> >     (3)
> >    Ovikā, 
> >    (4) Jñānajā, 
> >    (5) Bhadrakālī, 
> >    (6) Māheśī, 
> >    (7) Siṃhorī,
> >     (8)
> >    Dhanamardanī,
> >     (9) Gātrā,
> >     (10) Śāntā, 
> >    (11) Śeṣadevī, 
> >    (12) Vārāhī,
> >     (13)
> >    Bhadrayoginī, 
> >    (14) Yogeśvarī,
> >     (15) Mohalajjā, 
> >    (16) Kuleśī, 
> >    (17)
> >    Śakulācitā,
> >     (18) Tāraṇī,
> >     (19) Kanakānandā,
> >     (20) Cāmuṇḍā,
> >     (21)
> >    Sureśvarī,
> >     (22) Dārabhaṭṭārikā 
> >     and others.
> >     From each of these
> >    hundred-fold auspicious Śaktis of variety of forms were born therein.